# How should an English speaker pronounce "vice versa"?

Tags: pronunciation, latin, loanwords

When using *vice versa* in spoken English, I tend to just completely Anglicise it and pronounce it *vise VER-ser*, with only one syllable in *vice*.

The original would be something like *VEE-cay VER-sa*, but I often hear people use a hybrid pronunciation more like *VY-ser VER-ser*, with two syllables in each word.

Which is the "correct" way to say it?

French loan phrases seem to stay fairly true to the original pronunciation, e.g. *déjà vu* doesn't become *dedger-view* and *je ne sais quoi* isn't *juh nee sayz kwoy*.
So should *vice versa* be pronounced true to the original?

Comment: Uh. The Italian pronunciation is about as close to the original as the English one.

Comment: @RegDwighт Sorry, I meant Latin.

Comment: What’s with the *v* sound and soft *c*?  Those were not there in Latin.  Was more like /wike we:rsa/.

Comment: See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/87353), and follow the link to [the Traditional English pronunciation of Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin).  Also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56667 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/40671 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/97323 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/92374

Comment: The question of “How *should* an English-speaker pronounce. . . ?” is fundamentally unanswerable.  All you can ask is how English-speakers ***do*** pronounce something or other.

Comment: Just an interesting thing: some Hungarian speakers erroneously pronounce *vica versa* [veetsa verzah]. It sounds better for a Hungarian, it is, however, a nonsense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Vice versa](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/vice+versa)* should be pronounced as  /ˌvaɪs ˈvɜːsə/ or /ˌvaɪsi ˈvɜːsə/ in British English and  /ˌvaɪs ˈvɜːrsə/ or  /ˌvaɪsi ˈvɜːrsə/ in American English.

Comment: OED has /ˈvaɪsiː ˈvɜːsə/ [different stress from OALD] which I have never heard. I've always heard (and used) a schwa where *vice* has two syllables: /vaɪsə/. And I would have upvoted @Arch's answer because of that, but he deleted it.

Comment: I think the question is actually, "So should *vice versa* be pronounced true to the original?"

Comment: @Kris: I hope not, since there really is no 'original' pronunciation. Ciceronian? Silver Age? Mediaeval? Papal?

Comment: @TimLymington Which makes the assumption "The original would be something like VEE-cay VER-sa", and thence the very question, what?

Comment: @Kris No, the original would be WEE-kay WER-sa, which I certainly wouldn't advocate.

Comment: I (an Irish English speaker) actually use both of the two listed here as the American pronunciation (that is, the two that sound the *r* as indeed some British accents do as well). I've heard both so often that neither have completely dominated my own speech. I have noticed I tend more to /ˌvaɪsi/ when speaking myself, more to /ˌvaɪs/ when reading aloud, so the latter is probably a matter of my applying the more common spelling-to-pronunciation rules while reading (akin to how I'll read out some words plain wrong and then correct myself).

Comment: @Kris: Erroneous (drumroll). Specifically, the belief that an English phrase 'should' be pronounced as it would be if in the original language ignores the facts of Anglicization and pronunciation shifts; this particular phrase also has two pecularities, namely that no Latin-speaker would use those two words to mean what the English phrase means, and that Latin pronunciation changed markedly over the period when the phrase was (allegedly) coined. So yes, 'true to the original' is IMO meaningless, but '"correct"' is not, so long as the inverted commas are retained.

Comment: @TimLymington "As if it would be" sounds oddly German, and is certainly not something I can generate.  For me, it has to be "as it if were", and would certainly be marked wrong if it were any other way on this side of Atlantis.

Comment: @TimLymington You've totally overlooked the quote marks. I was quoting (questioning) the OP ('s assertion). Just check out the question once.

Comment: @Kris: yes, the error was OPs not yours. I wonder why you assume I thought otherwise, let alone "totally overlooked" anything.

Comment: @TimLymington I’m scambling/swapping words every which way lately. Seems to be too much hacking and too little sleep.  Or early-onset Alzheimer’s.

Answer (score 2):

In the middle of the twentieth century, a working class Australian would have pronounced it **vicky verser** because that would show (proudly) that he knew no Latin and had little regard for the snobs who did.

In fact, using the expression at all would have been a reluctant concession to polite society. The preferred form amongst his workmates would have been **and arse about face**.